# Use "the" instead of "a"

Tags: word-choice

> “As your noble Government has recently declared, your kingdom is currently undergoing ‘the biggest expansion of prison places in over a century’, with its ambitious projections showing an increase of the prison population from 82,000 to 106,000 within the next four years. **Quite the legacy**, indeed.

This if from (https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/julian-assange-belmarsh-london-wikileaks-dinner-b2333081.html).

Coming from a latin language the following phrase:

**"Quite the legacy"**

seems weird to me. I understand that he wants to be ironic, but my tendency was to use "Quite an irony" instead.

Could in this case the phrase "Quite an irony" be a better option? It is better to use "the"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*Quite the...*'  is a specific idiom. It means that someone, or something, is an example of something. It is different from when we say '*quite **a***' something.

Look up the word '*quite*' in a dictionary and you'll see it has two seemingly opposite meanings:

1. To the greatest extent; completely.
2. To a degree; somewhat.

So, for example, saying "*he is quite **a** gentleman*", could mean that person has gentlemanly qualities *to a degree*.

But, saying "*he is quite **the** gentlemen*" would mean that person typifies, or is an example of what a gentleman is.